# displayAllHeaders but for a single Markdown file

Tags: vuepress

I am trying to make a sidebar in VuePress with multiple sidebar groups. However, for one of the elements of the sidebar array, the element is a single file, rather than a group. For example:

```js
module.exports = {
  themeConfig: {
    sidebar: [
      {
        title: 'Group 1',   // required
        path: '/foo/',      // optional, which should be a absolute path.
        collapsable: false, // optional, defaults to true
        sidebarDepth: 1,    // optional, defaults to 1
        children: [
          '/'
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'Group 2',
        children: [ /* ... */ ]
      },
      "my_md_file",
    ]
  }
}
```

This works, but does not allow the user to see the subheadings of the Markdown file when on the children of other groups. I can use the `displayAllHeaders` to show the subheadings of the page even when not on it, but I only want this effect for a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this snippet instead of the condition in the `SidebarLink.vue` component on line 46 (I added just the first `else if` condition):

```js
  if (item.type === 'auto') {
    return [link, renderChildren(h, item.children, item.basePath, $route, maxDepth)]
  } else if (item.frontmatter.displayHeaders && item.headers && !hashRE.test(item.path)) {
    const children = groupHeaders(item.headers)
    return [link, renderChildren(h, children, item.path, $route)]
  } else if ((active || displayAllHeaders) && item.headers && !hashRE.test(item.path)) {
    const children = groupHeaders(item.headers)
    return [link, renderChildren(h, children, item.path, $route, maxDepth)]
  } else {
    return link
  }
```

Add this statement to the `frontmatter` part of your desired markdown file:

```
  displayHeaders: true
```